# Creating system tray right click menu C++

Tags: c++, winapi, unreal-engine4

I am trying to create Systemtray icon in Unreal Engine 4.
I am not a c++ expert. This is what i have scalped code from internet so far

```
#define NOTIFICATION_TRAY_ICON_MSG (WM_USER + 0x100)
AddTrayIcon(hwnd, 1, NOTIFICATION_TRAY_ICON_MSG, 0);
void AddTrayIcon(HWND hWnd, UINT uID, UINT uCallbackMsg, UINT uIcon) {

    //CREATE SYSTEN TRAY ICON.---------------------------------------------------------------------

    NOTIFYICONDATA  nid;

    nid.hWnd = hWnd;

    nid.uID = uID;

    nid.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_TIP;

    nid.uCallbackMessage = uCallbackMsg;
    FString ThePath = FPaths::ConvertRelativePathToFull(FPaths::RootDir()) ;
    FString GameName = FApp::GetName();
    
    ThePath.Append(GameName);
    ThePath.Append(".exe");
    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 12.f, FColor::White, ThePath);
    WORD id = 0;
    nid.hIcon = ExtractAssociatedIcon(nullptr, ThePath.GetCharArray().GetData(),&id);
    //LPCWSTR iconfile = "C:/Temp/icon.ico";
    //ExtractIconEx(iconfile, 0, NULL, &(nid.hIcon), 1);

    //strcpy(nid.szTip, "Tool Tip");

    //SEND MESSAGE TO SYSTEM TRAY TO ADD ICON.--------------------------------------------

     Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid);
    

}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {

    case NOTIFICATION_TRAY_ICON_MSG:
    {
        // This is a message that originated with the
        // Notification Tray Icon. The lParam tells use exactly which event
        // it is.
        switch (lParam)
        {
        case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        {
            const int IDM_EXIT = 100;
            POINT pt;
            GetCursorPos(&pt);
            HMENU hmenu = CreatePopupMenu();
            InsertMenu(hmenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, IDM_EXIT, L"Exit");
            TrackPopupMenu(hmenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON | TPM_BOTTOMALIGN, pt.x, pt.y, 0, GetActiveWindow(), NULL);
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Icon gets created but i cant rightclick and getpopup menu from it
Also i cant figure out how LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc() function gets triggered.

Can any1 help Thanks

Comment: You are not setting the `cbSize` member of `NOTIFYICONDATA`, and not zeroing out other unused fields, like `uVersion`, etc.  So `Shell_NotifyIcon()` does not know which version of the struct you are using, or which semantics to employ for the callback message (different versions use the `wParam`/`lParam` parameters differently). Also, you are not checking the return value of `Shell_NotifyIcon()` for failure. And, is your `WndProc()` associated with the `HWND` that you are giving to `Shell_NotifyIcon()`?

Comment: Where exactly are you calling `AddTrayIcon()` from, and where is `hwnd` coming from? Why not call it in the `WM_CREATE` message of your window? Or do you only display the icon under particular circumstances? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I am calling AddTrayIcon() on BeginPlay().
HWND hwnd = GetActiveWindow();
I didnt use cbSize  and uVersion bec i thought it wasnt needed here.
Shell_NotifyIcon() is creating a systemtray icon . So its not failing

Comment: "*`HWND hwnd = GetActiveWindow()`*" - why are you using `GetActiveWindow()` rather than your own window that you create? `GetActiveWindow()` is likely returning a window you are not expecting, which would explain why your `WndProc()` is not working. "*I didnt use cbSize and uVersion bec i thought it wasnt needed*" - then you didn't read the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/notification-area) well enough (or at all?). "*Shell_NotifyIcon() is creating a systemtray icon*" - that doesn't mean you associated the correct field values so it acts as you intend

Comment: GetActiveWindow is only way to get active window in my case. Also its returning right hmd since ii am using setwindowpos on it later and its working

Comment: "*GetActiveWindow is only way to get active window in my case*" - I highly doubt that, especially considering that you have a custom `WndProc()`, which means you must have an `HWND` associated with it, either via `CreateWindow/Ex()` or `SetWindowLong/Ptr(GWL_WNDPROC)` or `SetWindowSubclass()`, so you should be using that same `HWND` with `Shell_NotifyIcon()` instead of hunting for the `HWND` using `GetActiveWindow()`.

Comment: WndProc() is taken from examples i found on the internet while searching.
GetActiveWindow  is the onlyway to get window. Since window is created using UE4

Comment: you can't just define a `WndProc` and expect it to *magically* be called. You have to *explicitly* attach it to the window you are interested in. If you are not the creator of the window using `CreateWindow/Ex()` directly, then you must [subclass the window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview) instead using either `SetWindowLongPtr()` or `SetWindowSubclass()`. Unless UE4 exposes it's own hook for handling messages for the windows it creates on your behalf. It works help to see the code you are using to have UE4 make the window in question.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use SetWindowSubclass(). In my above code. I can't figure out its 2nd argument.  UE4 automatically creates its windows. I can't get that code as its buried deep inside its engine code somehwere

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-setwindowsubclass)? The 2nd parameter is simply a pointer to your `WndProc`. But you will have to adjust its parameters, as the `WndProc` you have shown is not compatible with `SetWndowSubclass()`, you need to add 2 more parameters to it: `LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)`, and also pass any unhandled messages to `DefSubclassProc()`. I have posted an answer with an example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not initializing the `NOTIFYICONDATA` correctly.  Specifically, you are not setting its `cbSize` or `uVersion` members, which directly influence how `Shell_NotifyIcon()` interacts with your app through the message you assign to the `uCallbackMessage` member.  This is discussed in detail in the following MSDN documentation:

[Notifications and the Notification Area: Define the NOTIFYICONDATA Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/notification-area#define-the-notifyicondata-version)

[Shell_NotifyIcon: Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyiconw#remarks)

[NOTIFYICONDATA structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-notifyicondataw)

Also, you say you want to display the popup menu on a **right-click**, but your `WndProc()` is looking for a **left double-click** instead.

But more importantly, you need to associate your `WndProc()` with the `HWND` that you give to `Shell_NotifyIcon()`, so that you can actually receive your `NOTIFICATION_TRAY_ICON_MSG` message at all.  Since you are trying to use an `HWND` that you are not the creator of, UE4 is the creator, you will have to [subclass the window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview#setwindowsubclass), eg:

```cpp
#define NOTIFICATION_TRAY_ICON_MSG (WM_USER + 0x100)

void AddTrayIcon(HWND hWnd, UINT uID, UINT uCallbackMsg, UINT uIcon);
void RemoveTrayIcon(HWND hWnd, UINT uID);
LRESULT CALLBACK SubclassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData);

...

HWND hwnd = ...; // GetActiveWindow(), etc
if (SetWindowSubclass(hwnd, &SubclassProc, 1, 0))
    AddTrayIcon(hwnd, 1, NOTIFICATION_TRAY_ICON_MSG, 0);

...

void AddTrayIcon(HWND hWnd, UINT uID, UINT uCallbackMsg, UINT uIcon) {

    //CREATE SYSTEM TRAY ICON.---------------------------------------------------------------------

    NOTIFYICONDATA nid = {};
    nid.cbSize = sizeof(nid);
    nid.hWnd = hWnd;
    nid.uID = uID;
    nid.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_TIP;
    nid.uCallbackMessage = uCallbackMsg;
    nid.uVersion = NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4;

    FString ThePath = FPaths::ConvertRelativePathToFull(FPaths::RootDir()) ;
    FString GameName = FApp::GetName();
    
    ThePath.Append(GameName);
    ThePath.Append(".exe");
    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 12.f, FColor::White, ThePath);

    WORD id = 0;
    nid.hIcon = ExtractAssociatedIcon(nullptr, ThePath.GetCharArray().GetData(), &id);
    //LPCWSTR iconfile = L"C:/Temp/icon.ico";
    //ExtractIconEx(iconfile, 0, NULL, &(nid.hIcon), 1);

    //strcpy(nid.szTip, "Tool Tip");

    //SEND MESSAGE TO SYSTEM TRAY TO ADD ICON.--------------------------------------------

    if (Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid))
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_SETVERSION, &nid);
}

void RemoveTrayIcon(HWND hWnd, UINT uID) {

    //REMOVE SYSTEM TRAY ICON.---------------------------------------------------------------------

    NOTIFYICONDATA nid = {};
    nid.cbSize = sizeof(nid);
    nid.hWnd = hWnd;
    nid.uID = uID;

    //SEND MESSAGE TO SYSTEM TRAY TO REMOVE ICON.--------------------------------------------

    Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, &nid);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK SubclassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_NCDESTROY:
            RemoveTrayIcon(hWnd, 1);
            RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, &SubclassProc, uIdSubclass);
            break;

        case NOTIFICATION_TRAY_ICON_MSG:
        {
            // This is a message that originated with the
            // Notification Tray Icon. The lParam tells use exactly which event
            // it is.
            switch (LOWORD(lParam))
            {
                case NIN_SELECT:
                case NIN_KEYSELECT:
                case WM_CONTEXTMENU:
                {
                    const int IDM_EXIT = 100;

                    POINT pt;
                    GetCursorPos(&pt);

                    HMENU hmenu = CreatePopupMenu();
                    InsertMenu(hmenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, IDM_EXIT, L"Exit");

                    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);

                    int cmd = TrackPopupMenu(hmenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON | TPM_BOTTOMALIGN | TPM_NONOTIFY | TPM_RETURNCMD, pt.x, pt.y, 0, hWnd, NULL);

                    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_NULL, 0, 0);

                    if (cmd == IDM_EXIT)
                    {
                        ...
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

That being said, you really should create your own window to handle the interaction with the System Tray.  You can call [`CreateWindowEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexw) directly to create a hidden [message-only window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows) and then associate your icon's `WndProc()` with that window.  You DO NOT need to use the UE4 window:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK SysTrayWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

...

LPCTSTR SysTrayWndClass = TEXT("MySysTrayWnd");

HINSTANCE hInst = ...; // GetModuleHandle(NULL), etc

WNDCLASS wc = {};
wc.lpfnWndProc = &SysTrayWndProc;
wc.hInstance = hInst;
wc.lpszClassName = SysTrayWndClass;
RegisterClass(&wc);

HWND hSysTrayIconWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, SysTrayWndClass, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, hInst, NULL);
if (hSysTrayIconWnd) {
    AddTrayIcon(hSysTrayIconWnd, 1, NOTIFICATION_TRAY_ICON_MSG, 0);
}
...
if (hSysTrayIconWnd) {
    RemoveTrayIcon(hSysTrayIconWnd, 1);
    DestroyWindow(hSysTrayIconWnd);
}

...

LRESULT CALLBACK SysTrayWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case NOTIFICATION_TRAY_ICON_MSG:
        {
            // This is a message that originated with the
            // Notification Tray Icon. The lParam tells use exactly which event
            // it is.
            switch (LOWORD(lParam))
            {
                case NIN_SELECT:
                case NIN_KEYSELECT:
                case WM_CONTEXTMENU:
                {
                    const int IDM_EXIT = 100;

                    POINT pt;
                    GetCursorPos(&pt);

                    HMENU hmenu = CreatePopupMenu();
                    InsertMenu(hmenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, IDM_EXIT, L"Exit");

                    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);

                    int cmd = TrackPopupMenu(hmenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON | TPM_BOTTOMALIGN, pt.x, pt.y, 0, hWnd, NULL);

                    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_NULL, 0, 0);

                    break;
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }

       case WM_COMMAND:
           if (lParam == 0 && LOWORD(wParam) == IDM_EXIT)
           {
               ...
           }
           break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Tried 1st one and doesnt seem to work. Only thing i changed was 
`PostMessageA(hWnd, WM_NULL, 0, 0);
switch (lParam)
  {
  case WM_RBUTTONDOWN://Right-click the tray to display the menu
  {
   GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 12.f, FColor::White, "Right Click sucess");
   const int IDM_EXIT = 100;
   POINT pt;
   GetCursorPos(&pt);
   HMENU hmenu = CreatePopupMenu();
   InsertMenu(hmenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, IDM_EXIT, L"Exit");
   TrackPopupMenu(hmenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON | TPM_BOTTOMALIGN, pt.x, pt.y, 0, hWnd, NULL);
break;
}`
RightClick Nothing happens

Comment: `HWND hwnd = GetActiveWindow()
SetWindowSubclass(hwnd, &SubclassProc, 1, 0);
 AddTrayIcon(hwnd, 1, NOTIFICATION_TRAY_ICON_MSG, 0);`

Comment: Also `switch (message)` should be `switch (uMsg)`  Right??

Comment: @sandy "*Tried 1st one and doesnt seem to work*" - you moved the location of the `PostMessage()`, it needs to be *after* the `TrackPopupMenu()`, [read the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackpopupmenu#remarks). But more important, `Shell_NotifyIcon()` doesn't send `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` when `NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4` is enabled, again [read the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyiconw#remarks). "*Also `switch (message)` should be `switch (uMsg)` Right??*" - yes, I have fixed it, thanks

Comment: Sorry what i mean to say was I changed PostMessage() to PostMessageA() Since the previous one was showing undefined.Its in same position below trackopoupmenu() Its just that in my previous comment i coudnt format it properly. So version 4 handles rightclick from WM_CONTEXTMENU: I deleted my added WM_RBUTTONDOWN Case and still nothing happens when i right click :(

Comment: @sandy `PostMessage()` exists, it is declared in the same file as `PostMessageA()`. It maps to `PostMessageW()` if `UNICODE` is defined in the project, otherwise to `PostMessageA()`. As for the rest, did you verify that `SetWindowSubclass()` is successful (does it return `TRUE`)? Are there *any* window messages being received by `SubclassProc()` *at all*?

Comment: I added a debug message 1st one before switch statement in subclass. This message gets displayed and 2nd Debug message after postmessage() which doesnt gets displayed. So its entering subclass but not switch statments

Comment: switch (lParam) Is not entering as anything below this  Debug message is not shown

Comment: OK, so the subclass is working in general, just not for the specific message(s) you are looking for. So, what `uMsg` values is the subclass *actually* receiving? Clicking on the tray icon *should* be sending your `NOTIFICATION_TRAY_ICON_MSG` message to the subclass, unless you are subclassing the wrong window to begin with (which I warned out about earlier).  This is why I *strongly* urge you NOT to use the UE4 window for managing the tray icon, create your own window instead.

Comment: I converted `UINT` to `int` to debug and value of `uMsg` was 1280

Comment: @sandy decimal 1280 is hex 0x500. That message is `WM_USER (0x400) + 0x100`, aka your `NOTIFICATION_TRAY_ICON_MSG` message. So the subclass is working to catch the tray icon activity.

Comment: But anything below switch (lParam) is not working.  But why??

Comment: OMG finally it works. I changed  `switch (lParam)` to `switch (LOWORD(lParam))` and it started working. Thanks a lot for all your Help

Comment: @sandy in this case, 1280 is in the range of `LOWORD()`, so `lParam` and `LOWORD(lParam)` are the same numeric value, so it should have worked before. But I just double-check ed the documentation and sure enough it says to use `LOWORD(lParam)` when using `NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4`. So be it. I have updated my answer to reflect this.